# How to remove extra values from a column in R

Tags: r, regex, date, data-cleaning

I am working with a dataset, and in the `date` column some of the values have letters as well. It's a large dataset, so I would need to be able to apply this to the entire column.

Example: `'XVII) (2016'`

Needs to be: `'2016'`

colname: `"release_date"`

`str_remove_all(movie_data$year, "XVII")` - This removed it from the single column, but other columns have 'I) or 'II), and some have periods in them. I can't get it to simply extract all these letters and special characters.
I also tried: `gsub("XVII",")",".","", movie_data$year)` - I just got an error message on that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metacharacter `\\D` to remove everything but numbers:

```
> string <- 'XVII) (2016'
> gsub("\\D", "", string)
[1] "2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use an `extract` rather than a `remove` strategy here.
We can use a regex to extract all sequences of four digits starting with 0,1 or 2, for all years between 0000 and 2999. The regex can be fine tuned, but seems to be ok for the use case described in the question.

**explanation of the regex**

```
[012]\\d{3}

[012] # one character matching 0, 1 or 2 followed by
\\d # any digit
{3} # this is a quantifier specifying a need for 3 consecutive matches for the preceeding character (\\d)
```

**data**

```
structure(list(index = 1:3, weird_dates = c("XVII) (2016", "2017", 
"XIV 2022")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df
  index weird_dates
1     1 XVII) (2016
2     2        2017
3     3    XIV 2022
```

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |> mutate(weird_dates = str_extract_all(weird_dates, '[012]\\d{3}'))

  index weird_dates
1     1        2016
2     2        2017
3     3        2022
```